# Linq Select with Where based on Dropdown values

Tags: vb.net, linq

I have a search page that has a series of 3 dropdowns that the user can use to limit the search results. Each of the dropdowns has an initial value of ALL. If any have a value other than ALL I need to include that as a WHERE statement.

This is where I become stuck. My Linq Select is...

```
Dim myComponents = From searchComponents In dc.Components _
                   Where searchComponents.Type = ddl_Type.SelectedValue _
                   AndAlso searchComponents.Size = ddl_Size.SelectedValue _
                   AndAlso searchComponents.WR = ddl_WR.SelectedValue _
                   Select searchCompnents)
```

At the moment my search will include all ddl selectedValues. I need to remove any that have a value of ALL. I hope I've explained correctly. Example if `ddl_Size.SelectedValue = "ALL"` then my statement would be...

```
Dim myComponents = From searchComponents In dc.Components _
                       Where searchComponents.Type = ddl_Type.SelectedValue _
                       AndAlso searchComponents.WR = ddl_WR.SelectedValue _
                       Select searchCompnents)
```

How can I achieve this in code. Thanks

Comment: Check about [Dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
Dim myComponents = From searchComponents In dc.Components _
                   Where   (ddl_Type.SelectedValue = "ALL" OrElse searchComponents.Type = ddl_Type.SelectedValue) _
                   AndAlso (ddl_Size.SelectedValue = "ALL" OrElse searchComponents.Size = ddl_Size.SelectedValue) _
                   AndAlso (ddl_WR.SelectedValue = "ALL" OrElse searchComponents.WR = ddl_WR.SelectedValue) _
                   Select searchCompnents)
```

Comment: This is not what I need. I fear I have not explained very well. There are no 'ALL' values in the Component table. If a user has selected Size = ALL then my Where statement should not filter on size at all. Thanks

Comment: @Mych And that is what this query does. It does not check the  Component table for `All` but the dropdown. And does the filtering only if the dropdown is not `All`

Comment: @Magnus i think OP mean that it need for all three dropdowns

Comment: @Grundy Ok, well it is the same technique for all of them. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @Mych if you see in query "ALL" check not in table, but SelectedValue of ddl

Comment: I understand. Have propagated to include all ddl and testing. Will let you know how I get on Thanks

Comment: You updated your answer... I concur I had same which is good... This works. Many Thanks.